# Graphics creation clear on panel control doesn't work

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, panel

I have a panel in my widows form. And I'm creating Graphics like in following code by creating a graphics

```
private void pnlDraw_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            if (startPaint)
            {
                using (g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
                {
                    if ( x != -1 && y != -1) 
                    {

                        Color mynewcolor = Color.FromName(myColor);
                        Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black, 5);
                        g.DrawLine(p, new Point(x, y), e.Location);
                        x = e.X;
                        y = e.Y;
                    }
                }
                pnlDraw.Invalidate();                    
            }
        }

 private void pnlDraw_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

            e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, Point.Empty);
        }
```

I'm trying to clear the panel, (clear what I draw on panel) in a button click event like this.

But it doesn't work? What should I do to clear the panel?

```
private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pnlDraw.Invalidate();
        }
```

Comment: Since you're using a Bitmap to draw Lines, you should *Clear* the Bitmap (fill it with the same Color of your `Panel.BackColor`). Maybe, you could Paint on the Panel instead of a Bitmap.

Comment: @Jimi Can you show a code example for that?

Comment: An example about what? Filling a Bitmap or painting on a Control's surface?

Comment: `using (Graphic g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {g.Clear(pnlDraw.BackColor);}`  Then call invalidate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to using LarsTech's answer

```
(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) { g.Clear(pnlDraw.BackColor); }
pnlDraw.Invalidate();
pnlDraw.Update();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pnlDraw.Invalidate();
        pnlDraw.Update();
    }
```

Comment: Both `Invalidate` and `Update` do the same thing: cause a Control to repaint itself. That is, they raise the `Paint` event. `Update` just forces the repaint to occur immediately. Calling them together like this is the same thing as calling `Invalidate()`. The Control will repaint itself, drawing the Bitmap.

Comment: @chathwind  I can, but I have to know what you want me to show you (as I have already asked). Do you need to draw those lines over an existing Bitmap? Or you want to draw lines (and maybe other shapes, in the future) on an empty canvas? Do you need to save those drawings to a Image file on disc afterwards? Add these details to your question and I'll answer it. Otherwise, it's an "Unclear what you're asking" kind of question.